# How to derive Fick's law of diffusion from kinetic theory?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, approximations, kinetic-theory, diffusion

I'm studying diffusion limits of kinetic equations and trying to figure out how one may (at least formally) derive Fick's law of diffusion (and hence the diffusion equation), i.e.
\begin{align}
\nabla\rho = \rho u,
\end{align}
where $\rho$ is the particle density and $u$ the drift velocity. I first tried to consider this from the point of view of Chapman-Enskog theory, whose zeroth order approximation gives us the Euler equation:
\begin{align}
\partial_t u +u\cdot\nabla u +\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla P = 0.
\end{align}
I consider steady state solution of the above, and since the diffusion constant is dependent on temperature, I fix the temperature, which naively reduces the euler equation to
\begin{align}
u\cdot\nabla u +\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla \rho = 0.
\end{align}
So the above approach doesn't quite work. To model diffusive effects, one needs to take the first order expansion of Chapman-Enskog; indeed from there we get the Navier-stokes equation, and also Fourier's law for temperature:
\begin{align}
\nabla T = q, 
\end{align}
where $q$ is the heat flux. From Fourier's law we may derive the heat equation $\partial_t T = \Delta T$ if we assume that the fluid has zero drift velocity.

However, one is not able to obtain the diffusion equation this way. My intuition is that in contrast to diffusion of temperature where the particles have no net movement, diffusion of actual particles has a drift velocity and one is not able to simply ignore this 'convective effect'. Indeed, a cloud of particles diffusing in free space would have the property that those particles furthest away would tend to have the highest velocities, so perhaps Brownian motion is not a good description for such diffusion processes. I'm starting to doubt if one may actually be able to see the diffusion equation as a diffusion limit of the full non-linear Boltzmann equation because of this...**Edit:** [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207043/) seems to confirm my guess that diffusion of a gas in a vacuum would not result in the diffusion equation.

**So in summary my question is: Can one obtain the diffusion equation by Chapman-Enskog expansion? If not, what kind of approximation methods, or additional assumptions on the system does one need to achieve this?**